# Determine relationship between users and age?

Tags: python, statistics, correlation, pearsons-correlation-coefficient

I would like to understand how to find an association between users, spam and email's age.
My dataset looks like as follows:

```
User      Spam      Age (yr)
porn_23    1         1
Mary_g     0         6
cricket_s54 0        4
rewuoiou   1         0
pure75     1         2
giogio35   0         10
viv3roe    1         1
```

I am looking at the correlation using Pearson. Is it right? I would like to determine the correlation between age and user: spam email should likely come from users having recent email's addresses (fake account / email).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using pandas, all you need to do is:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

corrMatrix = df.corr()
```

Then you can print the correlation matrix and also plot it using seaborn or any other plotting method.

```
sns.heatmap(corrMatrix, annot=True)
plt.show()
```

Hope this helps.